# Tengo el siguiente error de excepción en Laravel 5.6, ¿alguien puede ayudarme?

Tags: php, mysql

```
[![introducir el código aquí][1]][1]
```

[image: Me Manda este error, me gustaria saber si estoy especificando mal la ruta o que me falta, ahi esta el error, mi vista, mis rutas (utilizo un grupo de rutas, y mi controlador)][image: Este es mi controlador[![][2]]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0tfF.jpg)[[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUbU9.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Laravel a veces no es compatible con `{!! Form::open(['url' => 'posts/store']) !!}` por razones de seguridad Es por eso que el error ha sucedido. Puede resolver este error simplemente reemplazando el código por
`{!! Form::open(['route' => 'posts.store']) !!}` En tu caso seria:

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'departamentos.store'],['method'=>'POST']) !!}
```